# Flask: How to render a template AND save request.headers info?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to save objects made available by the `request.headers` in my Flask app.

I want to render my `index.html` upon page load, but I also want to grab the visiting user's email so I can use it for other functions / processes.

```
# routes
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def find_aad():
    aad_email = request.headers.get('X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME')  # aad email
    return aad_email
```

If I try to run `find_aad()` on its own,

```
user_email = find_aad()  # cant run
```

I will get the typical error: `Working outside of request context.`

How can I on an initial load of the website secure these headers and save them to an object without having these errors?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being daft, but... add it to the index above render_template? Or... can you give more information about your intent? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, if I add it to the line above render_template, I am not clear how I can then access and use the object `aad_email` in later lines of code / functions.

Comment: So, because the request is per, well, request, the reason you can't run it on its own is because the request object is only available when the user has called the index endpoint through the UI. So, in order to get that aad_email value later, you need some data structure that caches that value away (in an individual-user-keyed and thread-safe way, mind you) at a (hesitates to say this loaded word) "global" level.

Comment: Thanks for the insight -- I will look for other ways then to get at the capturing the user's email.

Comment: So, to kind of expound on what I said above, I'm referring to the fact that if you want at any given point to be able to retrieve that value, you're going to need to have some way to identify which user is calling you and use that identifier as the key to the data structure holding all these email values. So, like, determine that value, then create a dictionary at the same scope as the endpoints (above the index endpoint in the file) and add an element with the key-value pairing of identifier -> email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get at it this way, perhaps:

On that first call to index, you can create a UUID for the "session" and use that as an identifier for the user, then you pass that code back inside the rendered UI elements for stashing on the client-side. Then, on every subsequent call to the backend, you send that UUID with the rest of the request.

On those subsequent requests, you can access the email value via that UUID as the key to the data structure you're using to store client information on the backend.

This concept is the idea of a "session" with a "session id" that is common in client/server communications. Using sockets or possibly even built in or supplemental libraries for Flask would probably be a good idea instead of "rolling your own". Sorry if I'm being unhelpful or stupid - it's late where I'm at.

EDIT:

By request here's some simple pseudocode for this:

```
from flask import Flask
import uuid

...

uuid_to_email = {}

...

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    uuid_to_email[user_id] = request.headers.get('X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME')
    return render_template('index.html', uuid=user_id) # where it is implied that you would then use the uuid in the client-side code to story it and pass it back to the endpoints you want to do that with
```

Comment: Thanks again for the insight -- if you have any time for a sample of code that would be wonderful.

Comment: This code I posted above is just my rambling thoughts put to pseudocode, be aware. And there is definitely more for you to do, but that's the basic concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time -- agree; this looks non trivial!

Comment: No problem, one last thing: Flask does have "session", which is basically a dictionary for any time you're in a flask endpoint (like your index method) and you could simply say session['aad_email'] = <get the email> instead of what I'm doing here (which is just the same thing but makeshift). BUT, that requires you to be in an endpoint to get that value where the user whose email it is was the calling user of the UI. If you want the email to be available outside of that context you have to kind of blend in your own session management code. Good luck!

Comment: Quick question if you are still monitoring this; how can I use `uuid_to_email` in another function to get the key-value pair `uuid_to_email[user_id]`? Printing `uuid_to_email` returns an empty dict, but if I use something like: 

`@app.context_processor
def send_my_func():
    return {"uuid_to_email": uuid_to_email}`

I can access the values on other html pages, for instance.